# To delete a particular row in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In the below code, I have grid view in which I have 6 columns in which there are 1 `dropdown` and 5  `textbox`.My aim is to delete a particular row .I tried but I can't able to delete the particular row.

```
protected void gvInvoice_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dtCurrentTable = new DataTable();
    int RowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
    dtCurrentTable.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);

    SetPreviousData1(dtCurrentTable);


}
private void SetPreviousData1(DataTable dtCurrentTable)
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (dtCurrentTable != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = dtCurrentTable;
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Label lblProductID = (Label)gvInvoice.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("lblProductID_i");
                DropDownList txtProductName = (DropDownList)gvInvoice.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("EditableddlProductName");
                TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)gvInvoice.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtQuantity");
                TextBox txtProductPrices = (TextBox)gvInvoice.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("lblProductPrices");
                TextBox txtProfitPrice = (TextBox)gvInvoice.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtProfitPrice");
                TextBox txtTaxCalculation = (TextBox)gvInvoice.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("txtTaxCalculation");
                TextBox txtTotaPrice = (TextBox)gvInvoice.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("txtTotaPrice");

                lblProductID.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                txtProductName.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                txtQuantity.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                txtProductPrices.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();
                txtProfitPrice.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column5"].ToString();
                txtTaxCalculation.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column6"].ToString();
                txtTotaPrice.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column7"].ToString();

                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to bind the gridview datasource again.

```
  gvInvoice.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
  gvInvoice.DataBind()
```

place this code after deleting for datatable

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the row from the gridview but you are then going and calling databind again which is just refreshing the gridview to the same state that the original datasource is in.

Either remove it from the datasource and then databind, or databind and remove it from the gridview without redatabinding.

```
  protected void gvInvoice_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        myobj.myconnection();// connection created
        string mystr = "Delete table_name where water_id= '" + gvInvoice.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value + "'";// query
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(mystr, myobj.mycon);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        fillgrid();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your Datebase try giving delete stored procedure and apply on this grid datasource.